# Printing a number series row wise but increment column wise

Tags: java

I m creating a PDF file using Boxable library where i am printing a number series . Each page in the PDF will have 10 rows and 5 columns , after the 10th row a new page is added for to print the rest of the remaining numbers and so on. This is code for this and is  working correctly .

```
   public void createPdfColumnWise() throws IOException {
    float margin = 20;
    int firstNumber = 105;
    int lastNumber = 1005;
    int[] intArray = IntStream.range(firstNumber, lastNumber + 1).toArray();

    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

    doc.addPage(page);
    BaseTable table = pdfTable(margin, doc, page);
    int j = 0;
    int row = 0;
    while (j < intArray.length) {
      row ++;
      if(row > 10) {
      //if(row > 40) {  
        table.removeAllBorders(true);
        table.draw();
        row = 1;// reset
        page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        doc.addPage(page);
        table = pdfTable(margin, doc, page);
      }
      Row<PDPage> imageRow = table.createRow(25f);
      Cell<PDPage> cell = imageRow.createCell(8f, "");
      cell.setFontSize(6f); 
      cell = imageRow.createCell(10f,row + ")");
      cell.setFontSize(6f);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (j >= intArray.length) break;      
        String textValue =  String.valueOf(intArray[j]);
        cell  = imageRow.createCell(7f, textValue, HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
        cell.setTopPadding(6f);
        cell.setBottomPadding(6f);
        cell.setFontSize(12f);       
        j++;
      }
    }
    table.removeAllBorders(true);
    table.draw();
    String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File file = new File(userHome + "/Downloads/" + "Output.pdf");
    Files.createParentDirs(file);
    doc.save(file);
    doc.close();
  }


private BaseTable pdfTable(float margin, PDDocument doc, PDPage page) throws IOException {

    float tableWidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - (2 * margin);
    float yLocationNewPage = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - (2 * margin);
    boolean drawContent = true;
    boolean drawLines = true;
    float yStartPoint = yLocationNewPage + 50;
    float bottomMargin = 15;
    yStartPoint -= FontUtils.getHeight(PDType1Font.COURIER, 14) + 15;
    BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yStartPoint, yLocationNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, doc,
        page, drawLines, drawContent);
    return table;
  }
```

Now this is printing the values as shown below :

[image]

Now I am wondering if I can to print the values in this format shown below which increment the number series column wise :

[image]

So I need to get a logic of printing the values row wise but have the number series increment column wise. So far i am able to get the first row correct but from the second row i m not able to get this to work :

```
  public void createPdfColumnWise() throws IOException {
    float margin = 20;
    int firstNumber = 105;
    int lastNumber = 1005;
    int[] intArray = IntStream.range(firstNumber, lastNumber + 1).toArray();

    Stream<Integer> stream = Arrays.stream(intArray).boxed();
    Integer lastNum = stream.reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(null);

    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

    doc.addPage(page);
    BaseTable table = pdfTable(margin, doc, page);
    int j = 0;
    int row = 0;
    while (j < intArray.length) {
      row ++;
      if(row > 10) {
      //if(row > 40) {  
        table.removeAllBorders(true);
        table.draw();
        row = 1;// reset
        page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        doc.addPage(page);
        table = pdfTable(margin, doc, page);
      }
      Row<PDPage> imageRow = table.createRow(25f);
      Cell<PDPage> cell = imageRow.createCell(8f, "");
      cell.setFontSize(6f); 
      cell = imageRow.createCell(10f,row + ")");
      cell.setFontSize(6f);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (j >= intArray.length) break;  
        String textValue = null;
        if(i != 0 && (intArray[j] + 9) < lastNum) {
          textValue =  String.valueOf(intArray[j] + ( 9 * i));
        } else {
          textValue =  String.valueOf(intArray[j] );
        }
        cell  = imageRow.createCell(7f, textValue, HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
        cell.setTopPadding(6f);
        cell.setBottomPadding(6f);
        cell.setFontSize(12f);       
        j++;
      }
    }
    table.removeAllBorders(true);
    table.draw();
    String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File file = new File(userHome + "/Downloads/" + "Output.pdf");
    Files.createParentDirs(file);
    doc.save(file);
    doc.close();
  }
```

To use boxable you would need this dependency in your POM :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dhorions</groupId>
        <artifactId>boxable</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example :

```
int columns = 10;
int rows = 5;
int x = 105;

for(int j=0;i<columns;i++){
    for(int i =0;i<rows;i++){
        print(x + "   ");
        x += columns;
    }
    x -= rows*columns;
    x++;
    print(\n);
}
```

What do you think about this idea? I hope, this can help you to resolve your problem.